# Разбить строку на две переменные

Tags: php

Есть `$_POST['name_firstname']`. Надо по пробелу разбить на две переменные
`$name` и `$first_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($name, $first_name)= explode(" ", $_POST['name_firstname');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$expd = explode(' ', $_POST['name_firstname']);

$name = $expd[0];
$first_name = $expd[1]
```

Учитесь пользоваться поиском и **php.net**, либо **php.su**

Ответ для **ZhiV**

```
//$_POST['firstNameLastNamePatronymic'] =   'Андрей Аршинов Александрович';

$explode_ARR    =   explode(' ', $_POST['firstNameLastNamePatronymic']);

$firstName_STR  =   $explode_ARR[0];
$lastName_STR   =   $explode_ARR[1];
$patronymic_STR =   $explode_ARR[2];

var_dump($firstName_STR, $lastName_STR, $patronymic_STR);
```

Comment: С `list` красивее.

Comment: А если там Фамилия, Имя и Отчество...

Comment: @ZhiV если формат не изменился, то так :(дополню ответ).

Answer (score 1):

```
list($name,$sename) = explode(' ','имя фамилия');
```